# Two user IDs in one table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm currently importing my users and forum posts to a new database. The problem is that the import script adds new user IDs since it has to generate the user information in different tables. But when I import the forum posts (manually) it goes after the old user IDs.

What do you suggest for a solution for this? I can't really get my head wrapped around this so that's why I'm asking!

EDIT: I use a pre-made script to import users and I import the forum posts manually.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get it, didn't you have a users table too? Why the different ids?

Comment: How are you importing the new database?

Are you using a Database Tool to Export first and then import?

Comment: manually will take days, try to write a code, insert in users table get inserted id and then insert it to forum table

Answer (score 0):

The quickest/easiest thing that I can think of (If you can not find another way of mapping forums to users), is to create a temporary_id (temp_id) column in your users table.

The temp_id will have the same values as the id (in the users table) and it will just be a INT column.

One you got that, you can then import stuff into your new DB. Then, write a script that will use temp_id to get the right forums for each user and update its id with the new users id.

Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

Change the script so it adds the user id's as a new column e.g. IDdel then manually copy the db structure + data for your id column from the old database to the new one. Run your import script, delete the IDdel column.

Should be all good.

Comment: the problem is that the import script uses the auto-generated user_id in more then one table. So it saves some user info in a table called "user_info" and in one called "user"... That is my main problem, if the script won't find the user since the user ID needs to be chanced in more then one table.